# joining a list and a list of lists in python

Tags: python, mysql, list, pandas, pymysql

I have what should be a simple problem but 3 hours into trying different things and I cant solve it.

I have a pymysql returning me results from a query. I cant share the exact example but this straw man should do.

```
cur.execute("select name, address, phonenum from contacts")
```

This  returns results perfectly which i grab with

```
results = cur.fetchall()
```

and then convert to a list object exactly as I want it

```
data = list(results)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't include the header but you can get it with cur.description (which contains metadata including but not limited to the header). I push this into a list

```
Header=[]
for n in cur.description:
    header.append(str((n[0])))
```

so my header looks like:

```
['name','address','phonenum']
```

and my results look like:

```
[['Tom','dublin','12345'],['Bob','Kerry','56789']]
```

I want to create a dataframe in pandas and then pivot it but it needs column headers to work properly. I had previously been importing a completed csv into a pandas DF which included the header so this all worked smoothly but now i need to get this data direct from the DB so I was thinking, that's easy, I just join the two lists and hey presto I have what I am looking for, but when i try to append I actually wind up with this:

```
['name','address','phonenum',['Tom','dublin','12345'],['Bob','Kerry','56789']]
```

when i need this

```
[['name','address','phonenum'],['Tom','dublin','12345'],['Bob','Kerry','56789']]
```

Anyone any ideas?
Much appreciated!

Comment: You can just do `pd.read_sql_query("select name, address, phonenum from contacts", conn)` to obtain it as a Dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Addition of lists concatenates contents:

```
In [17]: [1] + [2,3]
Out[17]: [1, 2, 3]
```

This is true even if the contents are themselves lists:

```
In [18]: [[1]] + [[2],[3]]
Out[18]: [[1], [2], [3]]
```

So:

```
In [13]: header = ['name','address','phonenum']

In [14]: data = [['Tom','dublin','12345'],['Bob','Kerry','56789']]

In [15]: [header] + data
Out[15]: 
[['name', 'address', 'phonenum'],
 ['Tom', 'dublin', '12345'],
 ['Bob', 'Kerry', '56789']]

In [16]: pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
Out[16]: 
  name address phonenum
0  Tom  dublin    12345
1  Bob   Kerry    56789
```

Note that loading a DataFrame with data from a database can also be done with [pandas.read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

is that what you are looking for?

```
first = ['name','address','phonenum']
second = [['Tom','dublin','12345'],['Bob','Kerry','56789']]
second = [first] + second
print second
'[['name', 'address', 'phonenum'], ['Tom', 'dublin', '12345'], ['Bob', 'Kerry', '56789']]'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Other possibilities:**

You could insert it into data location 0 as a list

```
header = ['name','address','phonenum']
data = [['Tom','dublin','12345'],['Bob','Kerry','56789']]
data.insert(0,header)
print data
[['name', 'address', 'phonenum'], ['Tom', 'dublin', '12345'], ['Bob', 'Kerry', '56789']]
```

But if you are going to manipulate header  variable you can shallow copy it

```
header = ['name','address','phonenum']
data = [['Tom','dublin','12345'],['Bob','Kerry','56789']]
data.insert(0,header[:])
print data
[['name', 'address', 'phonenum'], ['Tom', 'dublin', '12345'], ['Bob', 'Kerry', '56789']]
```